# What does 'select()' do when all parameters are NULL or nullptr in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, select

I am having trouble understanding a certain operation in select() :

```
int select(int nfds, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds,
           fd_set *exceptfds, struct timeval *timeout);
```

I know that if nfds = 0, readfds = nullptr, exceptfds = nullptr and timeout = value select() works as a subsecond timeout.

But what happens if timeout is also nullptr or 0? Is this behavior undefined?

Comment: I could not find direct quote in the man page, but conclusive with other options, I would expect `select` with no descriptors and zero timeout to return immediately, and select with nullptr timeout to hang forever.

Answer (score 1):

The call will *wait for a signal*. Once a signal is delivered and successfully handled, the call will return. It is thus equivalent to a `pause(2)` call.

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.